# How can I make an uploads folder on my web server that can not be accessed from outside?

Tags: php, apache, file-upload, upload, xampp

This question has problably already been asked, but somehow I'm unable to find it or I need "special care" for my problem as I am a very beginner. So, please be a little patient with me here.

I am currently working on a PHP project where I need to enable my users to upload pictures for their profile. But I can not figure out how to upload the files so that noone else except the right people have access tto these pictures.

I've read something about 777, but I'm not sure if that's the way to go. I'm currently running XAMPP and Apache.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [should apache upload dir have 777 permissions or belong to www-data user?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6380331/should-apache-upload-dir-have-777-permissions-or-belong-to-www-data-user)

Comment: Thanks for the link. It's not really helping me tough as I'm lacking some more basic knowledge.

Comment: read this i think you will have your way http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php

Comment: Thank you for the link and all the answers. Yes it really is easy as some of you pointed out.

Comment: I wouldn't place `uploads` in public; but outside public and outside the root.

Comment: @Fred-ii- does that mean a folder below htdocs?

Comment: @sevku yes, exactly.

Comment: Can I access any folder through PHP or is there a limit?

Answer (score 2):

To configure your Apache to hide a folder from direct public access, the simplest way is to create a **.htaccess** file inside that folder with the following content:

```
Order deny,allow
deny from all
```

On XAMPP, you dont need to set any folder attributes (chmod) to be able to write into.

To save the uploaded file to the folder, use a php script:

```
<?php
if(!isset($_FILES['file'])) {
  echo 'No file received';
} else {
    $saveTo = 'uploads/' . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $saveTo)) {
      echo 'Upload successful';
    } else {
      echo 'Error uploading the file';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy to restrict a folder. Open notepad create a file and write

```
Deny from all
```

and save this file as `.htaccess` in the folder you want to restrict. thats all :)

Comment: Thank you. Yes it really is easy.